# Rotating an NSView

Tags: cocoa, rotation, nsview

I need to rotate the frame of an instance of `NSView` in such a way that its width becomes its height and its height becomes its width. The view contains a string and it is important that this string is rotated as well.

I had a look at `NSView's` `setFrameRotation:` but this rotates around the frame origin which is not what I want. I suppose that technically my requirement is not a rotation but more a mirroring at a 45 degree angle from the origin.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try Desire to rotate around centre

This piece of could should helper.

```
[NSView rotateByAngle]
```

Comment: My view appears stretched when I do this. In addition, other views (particularly an MKMapView callout) get rotated the same way as my map annotation.